# How to use SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm loading new level in my game using `SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync`, however after being loaded, scene isn't always activated. It happens when player changes his mind - after this he/she has to choose another level. I thought I can just load(async) another scene and it would overwrite the previous one, but the new scene didn't load at all(only if previously I loaded another one and didn't activate it). I think I should unload previously loaded scene before loading new one, so I did this: `SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync`, but I don't know how to finish unloading it. With `SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync` you can just `ao.allowSceneActivation = true;` (`ao` is `AsyncOperation`), but Unity documentation says nothing about unloading. Do you know how can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried using the synchronous counterparts to these methods for debugging purposes? You're adding in extra uncertainty in the world of C# async, so give the synchronous methods a try if applicable.

Comment: I tried using synchronous method and I think it unloaded the scene since I've got no errors, but still same outcome. I also tried prinitng out progress of `AsyncOperation` and after unloading the scene and trying to load new one asynchronously it stays on 0(should reach 0.9).

Comment: 1.What 's your Unity version? 2.Please update your code to show how exactly you are using the `UnloadSceneAsync` function.

Comment: My Unity version is 5.6.0f3. I'm not using `UnloadSceneAsync` because I need answer to my question first. I tried using `UnloadScene` and I did it like this: `SceneManager.UnloadScene(mapNameString);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those of you in the future reading this.
Here you go. I had an issue where my scene wasn't unloading.
Looking up, this question was here but no answers.
Here is how I solved my scene not unloading.

```
// Use a courotine so u dont freeze the ui
    public IEnumerator LoadScene()
    {
        // Load a scene in additive mode, meaning it wont unload the currently loaded scene if there is one
        var loadScene = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(
        GameScene.SplashScreen.ToString(),
        LoadSceneMode.Additive
        );

        loadScene.allowSceneActivation = false;

        // wait for the scene to load
        while (!loadScene.isDone)
        {
            if (loadScene.progress >= 0.9f)
            {
                break;
            }

            yield return null;
        }

        loadScene.allowSceneActivation = true;

        // HERE IS WHERE ALOT OF PEOPLE FAIL.
        // You need to wait for the scene to be loaded before you can unload the another scene.
        // This is because UNITY WILL NOT UNLOAD A scene if its the only one  currently active
        // If you look up, we allow scene activate only at 90% of the loading(for reasons im not sure but whatever), 
        // so now we have to wait for the rest of the 10% to load
        while (!loadScene.isDone)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        // Only when the scene is loaded we can unload the orginally active screen
        var asyncUnload = SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(GameScene.LoadingScreen.ToString());

        while (!asyncUnload.isDone)
        {
            if (asyncUnload.progress >= 0.9f)
            {
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Unloading...");
                break;
            }

            yield return null;
        }

    }
```

There you boyz go, ez